# Background services in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need to send the (lat,long) values of my device to the server in the interval of say every 5 minutes. I need to send this values even if my app is either killed or running in the background. In order to achieve this I think I need to use some services which can do this job. Couldn't find any reliable solution for this so far....Plz help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [`react-native-background-geolocation`](https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-geolocation).

Comment: Yeah you are right....just saw this   https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-geolocation